# gestunken flucht

Tags: meaning

I have heard this phrase in song by [Shpongle (Room 23)](http://music.zortam.com/showsongmain.php?id=11519472)

> I'm feeling very shpongled.
>
> Smashed, mashed, completely **gestunken flucht**.
>
> To be shpongled is to be kippered, mashed, smashed, destroyed...
>   Completely gestunken flucht.
>
> Feel so smooth. Everything's tingling.

It does sound German (or at least Germanic) 
([Google translate gives](https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/gestunken%20flucht): `aligned stunk` which does not make a lot of sense)

[Sample of the song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx1PjctB0-A&t=50s)

**What does it mean?**

Comment: That is not what is sung. It is possible however that those were written lyrics that the singer had.

Comment: @CarstenS Out of curiosity: is there a place where I can _hear_ what they sing? The link the OP gave refers to a .exe which I definitely won't download.

Comment: @PerlDog https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dx1PjctB0-A&t=50s in regards to link yeah don't click there - not sure what addwadre you'll get, I only pasted it for source of lyrics

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius Thank you. You link gives that (in)famous "Your country … NOT … GEMA" sign for German viewers, but [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1gPVmGh6I8) works (until YT figures out).

Comment: @PerlDog, it's on Spotify,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears to be pseudo German gibberish.

gestunken = past participle of stinken (to stink)
Flucht = noun, e.g., escape/flight; row of built structure, etc.

Given the 'psychedelic' style of the song, it may be meant as a reference or homage to the likes of *Can* and *Amon Düül* from the 1960s and 70s, the era of very experimental German alternative music, also labelled [Krautrock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krautrock) in English, which has been influential to rock/pop music in general .

Comment: "flucht" can also stem from "fluchen" (to swear) as in "He swears" -- "Er flucht". But I agree: it looks like gibberish.

Comment: Hi, I have added youtube link to the song hope this helps.

Comment: @MatasVaitkevicius In the video, it seems to be pronounced roughly like you would pronounce "flugged" in English, or "flackt" in German. So it's neither "Flucht" (escape, with short "u") nor "flucht" ((so.) swears, with a long "u"), and likely indeed some gibberish.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is only Pseudosprache, just made up words like the "shpongled" in "English". It's just the way a child would sing along with an english song without knowing the language properly, or as we did as kids when playing "Cowboys and Indians" talking out of the side of our mouths in a supposedly american flavoured English.

Theres no other meaning in this phrase other than it's understood to be a bad thing